# Why is this bash setup not aborting the execution even though I am using 'set -e'?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Version of bash being used:

```
mac> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0)
```

I have the following two files calls-failing-main.sh:

```bash
# calls-failing-main.sh
set -e

calls-failing-main_MAIN() {
  source ./failing-main.sh

  failing-main_MAIN && echo "failing-main_MAIN is saying its happy" || return 1

  echo "PrintC, should NOT be printed. (after 'return 1')"
}

calls-failing-main_MAIN
```

and failing-main.sh:

```bash
# failing-main.sh
set -e

failingFunc() {
  echo "failingFunc will return 1"

  return 1
}

failing-main_MAIN() {
  echo "PrintA, will 'return 1', on next line."

  failingFunc

  echo "PrintB, should NOT be printed. (after 'return 1')"
}
```

When I call:

```
mac> ./calls-failing-main.sh
PrintA, will 'return 1', on next line.
failingFunc will return 1
PrintB, should NOT be printed. (after 'return 1')
failing-main_MAIN is saying its happy
PrintC, should NOT be printed. (after 'return 1')
```

It appears that 'set -e' is not being respected at all?  (`failing-main_MAIN is saying its happy` is printed). Shouldnt it abort on the first uncaptured 'return 1' value with `set -e` set?

Comment: Per the bash manpage,: `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`) - "Exit immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status"  As such your return 1 from your function is not triggering an exit.   Further, there are peculiarities with using `set -e` as outlined here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?highlight=%28errexit%29#errexit

Comment: Since the exit status of `failing-main_MAIN` is being tested (with the `&& echo ...` part), `set -e` is effectively disabled within it, so the the error return from `failingFunc` doesn't trigger an exit. That means that `failing-main_MAIN` runs to completion, and its return status is determined by the status of the last command in it... which was an `echo` that succeeded. tl;dr don't use `set -e`, since it is confusing and prone to cause unexpected behavior. See [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)